# Having students assess what problems they're ready for

Tags: problem-solving, critical-thinking

Does anyone have experience with giving students a collection of problems where they have to assess which ones they have the knowledge to solve?

I was exploring the connection between video games and teaching, and noticed that video games provide a valuable meta-reasoning experience I haven't seen in the classroom. Some video games allow the player to select challenges they're not ready for, and so the player has to learn how to assess whether they are ready to face a particular challenge, or should leave and try something else.

Specifically, I'm thinking of a game like Elden Ring, which has a wide open world where the player can easily reach a large number of boss fights early on. Some of these are appropriate for a player at such an early level, and others are not. The game doesn't do much to indicate which boss fights are which, the player just has to try to assess for themselves whether they just need a little bit more practice or should come back later.

In the classroom, however, we usually present students with problems they know can be solved with what they've learned. One could imagine, instead, having a list of problems in a random order that students have to chip away at as the semester goes on. This would require them to reflect on the totality of what they've learned in the semester and what problems they know how to solve.

Has anyone tried anything similar? Specifically, some situation where you present students with problems only some of which they can solve with what they know, and have them sort through them? Does anyone know of any trials of this sort? I imagine it taking a lot of fine-tuning to get right.